# Fix Kitchen cabinets damaged due to fire

Tags: kitchens, cabinets

Please can you tell me what is the best way to fix these cabinets damaged due to fire. The right most cabinet has it's laminate peeling off and 3 other doors have some black stains. Is it best to just replace door with matching new doors or can this peeled laminate be removed and re-laminated. Attached are the pictures.
[image: Cabinet Picture]

[image: The right most cabinet]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will be best to replace any doors where the plastic laminate has been burnt, distorted or partially melted.

Comment: Yep, that is a vacuum formed vinyl (or similar) layer that is laminated onto the doors.  There's no real way to repair that finish once it has melted and started to peel off.

Comment: Thanks for the response, is this a Thermofoil door or a wood door?

Comment: @Umang: It looks like Thermofoil or something similar, probably over MDF? You could try using a heat gun to completely soften the coating so you can peel it all off, then remove any remaining glue residue, sand, prime and paint. Only you can decide if that amount of effort on your part is worth it.